# how to get media related info using twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter4j

I am new to twitter4j. How i can get media related info using twitter4j library? I want to get info about photos,videos and article summary present in tweet.Thanks in advance.Is getMediaEntities() method is enough for this purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hitting this request:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitter&include_entities=true

Then, look for any media_url elements; those will contain the URL to any photos. It may contain video links, so you'll have to filter for common image types (.png/.jpg/.gif/etc).

Check this as well: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-entities

Comment: thanks for help will i get web page related summary(some tweets have view summary link also which shows the summary of the shared web link) also in the media element or there is other way of getting that info

Answer (score 8):

Yes `Status#getMediaEntities()` is what you want but you can only get basic information about the media contained in the Tweet. For example if you wanted to search for Tweets matching a criteria and get media entities' types and URLs you could do:

```
Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
Query query = new Query("...");
QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
    for (MediaEntity mediaEntity : status.getMediaEntities()) {
        System.out.println(mediaEntity.getType() + ": " + mediaEntity.getMediaURL());
    }
}
```

There are other methods of retrieving Tweets using Twitter4J, e.g. using the Streaming API, take a look at the [code examples](http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html) on the Twitter4J web site for more information.