# How to extract image from a 't.co' URL contained in a tweet?

Tags: java, image, twitter, twitter4j

If I've got a link that looks like this from a tweet: https://t.co/xxxxxxxxxxx,
And I know that link contains and image. How do I extract that image from that post so I can use it on another page? I'm using twitter4j.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

I thought it worked by doing the following:

```
public String getImageUrlFromPost(String url) throws TwitterException {

        Query query = new Query(url);
        QueryResult result = this.getTwitter().search(query);
        System.out.println("The tweets found: " + result.getTweets()  +" with query " + url);
        for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
            for (MediaEntity mediaEntity : status.getMediaEntities()) {
                return mediaEntity.getMediaURLHttps();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Unfortunately `result.getTweets()` is empty when I pass my t.co link :(

Comment: A valid answer might be provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17295122/2849346 - The question in essence is a duplicate of the question related to that answer.

Comment: But the Query, queries only on hashtags afaik. Can I also query on url?

Comment: Alright seems like I can query on url's. Great, thnx!

Comment: Post your/the adapted Code Fragment as an answer, might provide upvotes.

Comment: It still doesn't work :(

Comment: passing a String parameter into a `twitter4j.Query` instance will only work for the actual content of tweet (140 characters). The API is not designed to search/query for media/image URLs like this.

Comment: So how can I get the url of the image that I just tweeted? I only got the t.co link and need the MediaURL. When I upload the image I see the link in the console that I need "[main] DEBUG twitter4j.HttpResponseImpl - {"extended_entities":{"media":[{"display_url":...." but it's a log message, so I can't get it in my code :(

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid, but you won't be able to query for or retrieve images behind `t.co`-URLs programmatically via Twitter4J API that way.

Basically, there are at least two types of URL formats to reference resources in Twitter:

1. Every URL which has the format http://t.co/randomstringhere is a *redirecting link* to another resource in the web (most likely: a Web Page) and the actual web page might be structured totally different for every single referenced page. Hence, there is no generic way of inferring the *xHTML* structure of the referenced page and consequently no proper way to retrieve what you're looking for.
2. By contrast, Twitter uses the URL format http://pbs.twimg.com/media/anotherandomstring.png (or .jpg or other formats) to reference *images* that have been shared in tweets with attached media files (here: images). Only in this case you can use `status.getMediaEntities()` and `mediaEntity.getMediaURLHttps()` to retrieve the URL's binary content of the actual image.

*Conclusion:*

Sadly, at least in 2016, there is no generic way to retrieve resources (media files) behind http://t.co/... URLs referenced in tweets via Twitter4J.